# Поднятие текста

Tags: android, textview, edittext

я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на EditText надпись поднималась наверх. В интернете я не нашел подобную информацию. Программа делается на платформе Android, через приложение Android Studio.
Вот пример из СберБанка как я хочу сделать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `В интернете я не нашёл подобную информацию` - (хоть это и осуждается, я скажу) плохо искали. К тому же, вопрос не содержит проблемы: `хочу сделать` - а что мешает? Но вот [пример запроса в поисковике](https://www.google.com/search?q=edittext+material+design+label+floating) и [пример результата запроса](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала смотрим это [Material Design Text Fields](https://material.io/components/text-fields), там есть дизайн и реализация.
Текст *телефон, карта или счет* это hint, при использовании TextInputLayout он поднимается вверх, как вам и нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще одна хорошая библиотека [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText)

подключается через `implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'`